# Change Git remote password used by NetBeans

Tags: git, github, netbeans, passwords, netbeans-8

I am working with Netbeans IDE 8.2 and a GitHub repository I push changes to. When i first set up the GitHub credentials i made a mistake while typing the password and left checked the "Remember" field.

Now every time i try to push to origin, i receive an http error which says that the credentials are wrong - and I am sure they are, but I can't change them. I tried searching the options menus, the project settings and the "Team" menu, but I'm probably missing something.

How do I change the default password for GitHub in NetBeans?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right click your project and go to Git -> Remote -> Push...
Select 'Specify Git Repository Location', update your password, click Next.
It may give you error again. Close the popup and try pushing again. You should be able to push now.