# Netbeans JGit github password authentication deprecated,. how to reset?

Tags: github, netbeans, oauth, access-token, jgit

I am using netbeans 8.2 to push to github but now get messages saying

> You recently used a password to access the repository at XXX with git using JGit/3.6.2.201501210735-r.
>
> Basic authentication using a password to Git is deprecated and will soon no longer work. Visit > https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more > information around suggested workarounds and removal dates.
>
> Thanks,
> The GitHub Team

How can I reset my authentication to enter a github token (https://github.com/settings/tokens) instead of my password?

Answer (score 4):

I've just faced with it.
Just generate token and use inplace of password.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-5252

To reset the password, I followed the instructions at [Change Git remote password used by NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48994056/change-git-remote-password-used-by-netbeans), and entered my new github token to the password field. Copied from that answer:

> Right click your project and go to Git -> Remote -> Push... Select 'Specify Git Repository Location', update your password, click Next. It may give you error again. Close the popup and try pushing again. You should be able to push now.

For my new token, since I only want to pull and push to the project, I used the default repo options.