# Can't connect to github repository in Netbeans 12.4

Tags: git, github, netbeans

I'm running Netbens 12.4 and OpenJDK 16.0.2 and also tried 11.0.02 on a Win 10 laptop. I've been a long time Netbeans user and never run into this problem. Just installed it on my laptop for the first time. Keep getting "invalid credentials for repository at..." It's a private repository.

Was trying to push a repository to github that kept failing. I can use git on command line and desktop client. Checked the proxy configuration and set it to No Proxy in case it wasn't picked up in the settings. Tried the "Test Connection" and I got an exclamation in a red stop sign. No message. Couldn't find any error messages. Nothing notable in messages.log. I'm not using a proxy and I tried disabling the Windows Defender firewall.

I don't even know where to start to look for what might be wrong as I can't get any errors.

I can download maven dependancies fine in netbeans. Edit: I can also clone a public respository.

I'm using the username and password I use to log into the github website.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49698917/813999

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk thank you but no it doesn't help. I tried it from my desktop too and I'm not able to clone either. If click on "Proxy configuration..." and then click "Test Connection" it fails but I don't see an error anywhere, just the red stop sign with exclamation point. Different computer, different network, same issue. I can download maven dependencies fine. The username and password should be the same I use to log into github website right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the intended behavior but it doesn't work with the password I use to log into github.com via the browser and other applications. I needed to create a Personal Access Token on and use that as the password.

1. Log into github.com and in the top right click on user name and select **Settings**
2. Scroll down and click on **Developer Settings** on the left sidebar menu
3. On the left sidebar click on **Personal Access Tokens**
4. Click on **Generate New Access Token**
5. I made a note to know it was for netbeans
6. Set the expiration you want, and make sure to grant access to all the **repo** items
7. It will generate a token. Copy this token and be aware that you can't access this again but you can regenerate a new one.
8. Back in Netbeans when trying to access git remote use the token you just copied instead of the password.

Comment: thank you! it worked! 

but since then our regular passwords stopped working?

Comment: I remember a warning about JGit protocol being deprecated prompting in some of the lastest releases. Must be related to it.